# How to use 'not equal' to filter on users attribute in a URL using REST Identity API in Bonita

Tags: rest, url, get, bpmn, bonita

I'm using Bonita in a 7.3 Version. My goal is to use the identity API to gather information about my users, such as it's name etc. The thing is : I'm trying to catch all the users in a certain group of users with the following API request :

```
http://localhost:XXXXX/bonita/API/identity/user?a&f=role_id=101&f=manager_id=0
```

As we can imagin, this query gives me a list of users, with a role_id = 101 and no managers.

And then, I want to filter on a new attribute, which is the id : I d'ont want the user with the id equal to 101. I've tried this :

```
http://localhost:XXXXX/bonita/API/identity/user?a&f=role_id=101&f=manager_id=0&f=id!=101
```

But it does not work. Is it even possible to use the `!=` element in Bonita ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no != option within the f={filter name}={filter value}